# mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > mediaPlayer.getDuration() at the end of playing mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm playing mp3 file streamed from the network in my application, some mp3 files has weird behavior: `mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` is larger than `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` at the end, for about 3 seconds.

The mp3 files are [CBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_bitrate) encoded.

What might be the reason of this?

Comment: when you stream from the network, the getDuration() can be -1, refer this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration()

Comment: @ArunShankar the `getDuration()` is not `-1` in my case, it's the correct value

Comment: @wong2 : post your code and url of that song

Comment: @AnandSavjani I can't post the audio file due to copyright reason

Comment: Does this happen for all mp3s? Did you try mp3s which are not CBR encoded? Just asking because we had some issues with mediaplayer in the past, with wrong meta-data within mp3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by converting the mp3 files, this is the command I'm using:

`lame --mp3input -t -m s -b 128 --cbr input.mp3 output.mp3`

Answer (score 2):

There is a few reasons you can get this behavior.

First it appears that people had better results using mp3 files at exactly `44100Hz`, because apparently the `MediaPlayer` class is assuming this value and scale the time accordingly, making strange values for files not using this sampling.

You also need to check the mode of your channels, and try using Joint Stereo or forced L/R Stereo. Joint should be the default, but your files might have been previously bad encoded, so it's worth trying. It's interesting to note that Forced L/R Stereo might loose quality for the same bitrate as Joint.

It would also be useful to check the output of `soxi` which is part of the [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) package (you can also do it with ffmpeg), that will give you the number of channels, Sample rate, Bit Rate and Number of Channels.

Also you might want to check the raw content of the mp3 file if you did some treatment on them using any app for the presence of garbage xml content that might have been inserted during the export.

If you have the possibility to modify the mp3 files you're streaming, (which sounds like you do since you can tell the bitrate) these are what I would try first. If it's more like user-upload kind of stuff, maybe you should have a look to another solution instead, like [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) which has a few thousands stars and active development. It wraps the `MediaPlayer` api still, but worth a try.

You also have to consider that it might be a threading problem, where the player would stop playing, but the timer would actually keep going, giving you this result where it's superior to the actual duration of the song. 3 seconds seems a bit too much to explain it by that, but that's just a thought.

Comment: By using the `-b` option of `lame` you changed the encoding of the files that was apparently wrong and fixed it to a valid one. My answer covered this part even if it didn't provided the exact command to type since the problem might have been a lot of other things and was left for you to figure out (there is also system restrictions for the soft you could use etc). "Anyway" is not really the right word here.

Comment: I really appritiate your time, but your answer didn't help in my case. That's why I can't accept your answer.

Comment: Hum I see sure, I'm just trying to understand ;) So previously you tried using lame with -b but without specifying the mode and after switching to L/R it started working?

Comment: Okay, I added a few info about modes then